# Mount an external hard drive if connected to the same folder

Tags: macos, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, mount

I am using `MacOS Mojave 10.14.3`, and I want to achieve something similar to this.

In `Ubuntu` I have this configuration to be able to mount an external disk to the same folder using its UUID. In this example it will mount to `/media/external1/`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=9e474079-5228-40c4-8bb2-36218c11c467 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=1C5A-B867  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=5C2A-23AD /media/external1/    exfat        nofail,auto,noatime,rw,user 0 0
```

This allows me to mount an external disk (only if it is connected) to the same `path/folder` when I turn on the computer or I connect the disk

Is there a way to achieve this in MacOS 10.14.3?

Comment: It will auto-mount to /Volumes with no need for an fstab entry. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Tetsujin, thank you, you are right, I was not clear what I want to achieve, I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fstab` on macOS pretty much exactly as on Linux. Check out `man fstab` in a Terminal to see documentation specific to macOS, particularly for valid filetypes and options. You can get the UUIDs with `diskutil info /dev/diskX`, where X corresponds to the device number (see `diskutil list`). Use `sudo vifs` to safely edit/create `/etc/fstab`.